# Using arrow function in then chaining results in different output

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise, es6-promise, arrow-functions

I am working with promises and here is my code:

```
function call1() {
   return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
     resolve('resolved from call 1');
   });
}

function call2(result) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    resolve(result + ' - resolved from call 2');
  });
}

function callP() {
  call1()
    .then(result => call2(result))
    .then(function(result) {
      console.log(result);
    });
}
callP();
```

This gives me the output:

> resolved from call 1 - resolved from call 2

But when I change:

```
.then(result => call2(result))
```

to:

```
.then(function(result) {
  call2(result);
})
```

The result is `undefined`.

As per my understanding:

```
function(result) {
    call2(result);
}
```

and:

```
result => call2(result)
```

Mean the same thing. Am I doing anything wrong here?

Comment: `result => call2(result)` is an implicit return whereas `function` syntax requires an explicit return to do the same thing

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Interestingly enough, the canonical doesn't go over implicit returns. I guess it's more semantic and side-effect difference than syntactic difference.

Comment: @AndrewLi You are right, it doesn't mention the `return`. I'll reopen this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
.then(result => call2(result))
```

Implicitly returns the result of `call2` and is equivalent to this:

```
.then(result => { return call2(result); })
```

What you're looking for is this:

```
.then(function(result) {
    return call2(result);
})
```

Answer (score 3):

They are not the same. This [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```
result => call2(result)
```

Implicitly returns the return value of `call2(result)` because arrow functions allow for the following syntax:

```
( … ) => expression
```

Where `expression` is the return value of the arrow function. For example:

```
() => 1 + 1
```

Is the same as:

```
() => { return 1 + 1 }
```

And:

```
function() {
  return 1 + 1;
}
```

The regular function does not return anything:

```
function(result) {
  call2(result);
}
```

That callback doesn't return anything *explicitly* (it defaults to `undefined`). Because you do not return anything, the second chained `then` receives `undefined` as the value of the `result` argument and thus logs `undefined`. To achieve the same effect, return the value explicitly:

```
return call2(result);
```

This will pass the result of the first `then` to the second `then` and log correctly. Also note, arrow functions and regular functions bind `this` differently. `this` in arrow functions is the `this` of the enclosing scope -- they don't bind it themselves while regular function expressions depend on how they're called -- usually being `window` or `undefined` in strict mode. Besides the syntactical differences, I recommend reading  [Felix Kling's phenomenal answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/arrow-function-vs-function-declaration-expressions-are-they-equivalent-exch) on the topic.

Comment: *"...the regular function does not return anything"*. This is incorrect: JS functions always return something.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Yeah, if it were taken literally. I've edited, thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 2):

The main issue here is that you forgot to `return` a value in your first function. So if return `call2(result)` in the first function, like what i've done below:

```js
function(result) {
    return call2(result);
}
```

You will get the same result as using the arrow function you mentioned in your second code:

```
result => call2(result)
```

With regards to if the first function is the same as the second one ( assuming you've added the return in the first function), while they may achieve the same thing, they are not quite the same. The main difference is with the context of `this`. I quite like the explanation of arrow function and how it affects the value of `this` by MDN which you can view [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Comment: Well, they technically aren't equal because of the different for the value of `this`, but in this case `this` isn't being used so they would perform the same if the `return` was added.  I think it's important to not let anyone forget that different with arrow functions.